# Angular 4 : can't redirect from inside a subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

After a number of unsuccessful tries, I still can't achieve to redirect from inside a subscribe.

I wanna catch the error code 401 to redirect the user to the login page so in the `http.get.subscribe` if I have an error and if it's a 401 I execute `goLogin()`.
This function must tell the router to navigate to the login page but it doesn't. Everything's working except routing.

Here's my code :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

import { CategoryFactory } from  "./../factory/category.factory";
import { StatusFactory } from  "./../factory/status.factory";
import { TicketFactory } from  "./../factory/ticket.factory";

import { HeaderProvider } from  "./../provider/header.provider";

import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class TicketService {

    public liste: TicketFactory[] = [];

    constructor(private http: Http, private requestoptions:HeaderProvider, private _router:Router, private r:ActivatedRoute, private zone: NgZone) {

        this.http.get('/issue', this.requestoptions.options)
        .map(
            res => res.json(),
            err => err.json()
        )
        .subscribe(
            (liste:any) => {
                liste.forEach((l) => {
                    let t = new TicketFactory(
                        l.id,
                        l.title,
                        l.author,
                        l.text,
                        l.email,
                        new CategoryFactory(l.category.id, l.category.label),
                        new StatusFactory(l.status.id, l.status.label),
                        l.createdat,
                        l.priority,
                        l.sendto
                    );

                    this.liste.push(t);
                })
            },
            (err:any) => {
                if(err.json().code === 401) {
                    this.goLogin();
                }
            },
        )
    }

    goLogin = (): void  => {

        this.zone.run(() => { console.log('go login'); this._router.navigate(['login']) })
    }

    getList = () : TicketFactory[] => {
        return this.liste;
    }

    getTicket = (idticket):any => {
        return this.http.get('/issue/' + idticket, this.requestoptions.options).map(res => res.json());
    }

    deleteTicket = (idticket):any => {
        return this.http.delete('/issue/' + idticket, this.requestoptions.options)
            .toPromise()
            .then()
            .catch();
    }
}
```

Here's `app.routes.ts`

```
import { Routes }                       from '@angular/router';

import { FormComponent }                from './components/form/form.component';
import { LoginComponent }               from './components/login/login.component';
import { SigninComponent }              from './components/signin/signin.component';
import { TicketComponent }              from './components/ticket/ticket.component';
import { TicketListComponent }          from './components/ticketslist/ticketlist.component';

import { OnlyLoggedInUsersGuard }       from './components/guard/guard.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'signin',
        component: SigninComponent,
        canActivate: [OnlyLoggedInUsersGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'tickets/:id',
        component: TicketComponent,
        canActivate: [OnlyLoggedInUsersGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'tickets',
        component: TicketListComponent,
        canActivate: [OnlyLoggedInUsersGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: FormComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
    }
]
```

It goes into `goLogin();` and `console.log(...)` is executed but it doesn't redirect to the login page.

Here's the console output if it can help:

```
14:36:07.962 zone.js:2263 GET http://localhost:4200/user 401 (Unauthorized)
14:36:08.036 core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Response {_body: "{"code":401,"message":"Invalid authentication token"}", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: Headers…}
14:36:08.048 zone.js:2263 GET http://localhost:4200/category 401 (Unauthorized)
14:36:08.110 core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Response {_body: "{"code":401,"message":"Invalid authentication token"}", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: Headers…}
14:36:08.116 zone.js:2263 GET http://localhost:4200/issue 401 (Unauthorized)
14:36:08.122 ticket.service.ts:53 go login
14:36:08.479 zone.js:2263 GET http://localhost:4200/status 401 (Unauthorized)
14:36:08.575 core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Response {_body: "{"code":401,"message":"Invalid authentication token"}", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: Headers…}
```

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: It seems correct, have you tried to put '/' before 'login'?

Comment: `.map(res => res.json(), err => err.json())` ? Have you tried to log the error in the error handler?

Comment: No errors in console.
With '/' nothing changes.
I tried but I didn't helps me.

Comment: will you please also post routes.ts ?

Comment: I edited my post to add it.

Comment: Have you tried using the catch operator (with the get) to catch errors?

Comment: `catch()` isn't available for `Observable` but only for `Promise`

Comment: Am I missing something? Is catch not available for the type of observables in Angular?  http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/catch.html

Comment: I assume that it redirects you to the login, but then it checks for Authorization again! don't you think. As i see from your logs.

Comment: It doesn't redirect me. It continues to do requests to the backend. It should stop after `this.list = listtickets.getList();` in `this.listCategory = listcategory.getList();
        this.listStatus = liststatus.getList();
        this.listSendTo = listUser.getList();` but it doesn't.

Comment: Try to create new property in your class like `private auth = false;` then use takeWhile operator after map `.takeWhile(() => !this.auth)` then on error set the `this.auth = true` and put `this._router.navigate(['login'])` like complete cb of the Subscriber as a thirth param.

Comment: I just tried it but it seems to be incorrect. Check my answer with code down below to tell me if I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
 this._router.navigateByUrl(['login']
```

Comment: With `this._router.navigateByUrl('login')` it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `this.zone.run(...)` as it shouldnt be required. The app should remain in the angular scope. You also need the `/` infront of the route.

Try swapping:

```
goLogin = (): void  => {
    this.zone.run(() => { console.log('go login'); this._router.navigate(['login']) })
}
```

to the following:

```
goLogin = (): void  => {
    console.log('go login');
    this._router.navigate(['/login']) })
}
```